# mysql loop with variable incrementing

Tags: php, mysql

I added a new row to my table, keeping track of the game number in the round, thus it will have values 1,2,3,4.... when round ends it will be reset to 1 etc

it will be pretty simple to code this with php or similar just doing

```
$x=1++
while(round == 1){
INSERT INTO events (game_nr) values ('$x')
$x++
}
```

Is there something similar I can use as the above code on a mysql db using only mysql?

Comment: may be you are searching for "procedures" in mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read manual [Defined Variables in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

```
SET @x := 1; -- Define a variable
INSERT INTO events (game_nr) values (@x := @x + 1)
```

Comment: beware this may not give you what you want if you expect some sort of ordering to the numbers

Comment: Thanks!! Should I put a WHERE clause here aswell like `SET @x := 1; -- Define a variable
INSERT INTO events (game_nr) values (@x := @x + 1) WHERE round='1'`